# Woocommerce Live PHP Order Feed in XML

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce, feed

Okay so I've been trying to get my head around the API for the past couple of hours and don't seem to be able too, it seems the only way to output the order details in the specific order, or at least similar... is JSON but I need it in XML.

This is the format I need:

```
<xml>
  <order>
    <billingInfo>
      <method>Paypal</method>
      <firstName>Paul</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
      <company/>
      <address>Address</address>
      <address2/>
      <city>City</city>
      <state>State</state>
      <postcode>A12 3BC</postcode>
      <country>GB</country>
      <email>JohnSmith@email.com</email>
      <phone>07123456789</phone>
    </billingInfo>
    <shippingInfo>
      <firstName>Paul</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
      <company/>
      <address>Address</address>
      <address2/>
      <city>City</city>
      <state>State</state>
      <postcode>A12 3BC</postcode>
      <country>GB</country>
      <shippingTotal>123</shippingTotal>
      <shippingTax>12</shippingTax>
      <shippingMethod>Shipping Method</shippingMethod>
    </shippingInfo>
    <customerInfo>
      <email/>
      <firstName/>
      <lastName/>
      <username/>
      <taxExempt>true/false</taxExempt>
    </customerInfo>
    <orderInfo>
      <orderId>1234</orderId>
      <transactionId/>
      <customerIp>1.234.56.789</customerIp>
      <datePaid/>
      <taxTotal>100</taxTotal>
      <grandTotal>500.00</grandTotal>
      <customerNote/>
      <taxMethod>VAT 20%</taxMethod>
      <lineItems>
        <item>
          <productId>1234</productId>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
          <name>
            Product Name
          </name>
          <subtotal>500</subtotal>
          <subtotalTax>100</subtotalTax>
        </item>
      </lineItems>
    </orderInfo>
  </order>
```

The end goal is to have this script run on a CRON job hourly to pull all orders in.

Thank you for any help/advice.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. 

Please clarify what you mean with this part: "to pull all orders in and have a local file be able to communicate with it". Do you want to export all orders to sync it with a local file?

If I'm right, there are several plugins for this purpose like WP All Export. If you don't want to buy a plugin, you'll need to transform the json-string to xml by yourself, which shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for getting back to me, I'm not going to have it communicate with a local file now after a long debate as to whether I should, I'm just trying to get it to essentially have a feed at a url (let's say orderstracker.php) and once on that page it'll display all site orders in the above mentioned format as an XML file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, here's my solution to anybody else in the future who may need help getting Woocommerce order data through XML.

Here's a basic example of what sort of data you can get:

```
<?php


header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";

    include(__DIR__ . "/../wp-load.php");
    global $woocommerce;

    $filters = array(
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'paged' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($filters);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) {

        $loop->the_post();

        $order = new WC_Order(get_the_ID());
        $customer = new WC_Customer($order->get_order_number());        

        foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {

            $output .= '<xml>';
            $output .= '<paymentInfo>';
            $output .= '<method>' . $order->payment_method . '</method>';
            $output .= '</paymentInfo>';
            $output .= '<personalDetails>';
            $output .= '<firstName>' . $order->billing_first_name . '</firstName>';
            $output .= '<lastName>' . $order->billing_last_name . '</lastName>';
            $output .= '</personalDetails>';

            $output .= '<item>';
            $output .= '<productId>' . $lineItem['product_id'] . '</productId>';
            $output .= '<quantity>' . $lineItem['quantity'] . '</quantity>';
            $output .= '<name>' . $lineItem['name'] . '</name>';
            $output .= '<subtotal>' . $order->cart_tax . '</subtotal>';
            $output .= '<subtotalTax>' . $order->total_tax . '</subtotalTax>';
            $output .= '</item>';

           $output .= '</xml>';

           echo $output;

        }
    }
?>
```

And the output:

```html
<xml>
  <paymentInfo>
    <method>other</method>
  </paymentInfo>
  <personalDetails>
    <firstName>first K</firstName>
    <lastName>second K</lastName>
  </personalDetails>
  <item>
    <productId>561</productId>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <name>
      Woodlets Premium Wood Pellets - Full Pallet - 980kg
    </name>
    <subtotal>0</subtotal>
    <subtotalTax>0</subtotalTax>
  </item>
</xml>
```